# multicast_to_unicast with hostapd on RPi

Tags: linux-kernel, raspbian, realtek, hostapd, multicast

I'm trying to use hostapd's multicast_to_unicast feature.
The AP is working fine, but I get this error:

```
nl80211: multicast to unicast not supported on interface wlan0
```

I'm on Raspbian with next kernel (4.14.21-v7+ #1095) and with the latest hostapd (compiled from git).

As far I can see it means that the nl80211 I'm using does not support `NL80211_CMD_SET_MULTICAST_TO_UNICAST` command, but I don't understand why and what should I do.

**Update**: according to [source](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.14.y/net/wireless/nl80211.c#L12276) the error is returned when `set_multicast_to_unicast` is NULL, and that field is populated by driver.
My card is based on rtl8812au and, for what I see in [the driver](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au/blob/master/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c#L5031), `set_multicast_to_unicast` is not defined. 
The only way to get M2U working on this card is to write my own conversion routine and put it in the driver, right?

**Update 2**: Yes, I got that error since driver does not provide a implementation for  `set_multicast_to_unicast` in its `cfg80211_ops`.
But I noticed that rtl88XX drivers do M2U by default (if not explicitly disabled at compile/load time)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Could you describe your particular situation in which multicast-to-unicast conversion does something useful? Because I have a hard time imagining such situations, but that's probably just me.

Comment: With multicast the highest speed you can achieve is the speed of the slowest client. If you have a client with a weak signal it'll slow down all the other clients, regardless of their signal strenght. With multicast-to-unicast each packet is transmitted at the highest speed supported by the client.

Comment: Maybe my understanding of hostapd is flawed, but I thought that with encrypted channels you'll have to send each multicast packet to each receiver individually anyway (because it's encrypted individually), and I'd assume that this happens at the highest speed between AP and STA, and what multicast-to-unicast does is just rewrite the broadcast address into a unicast address? Which is probably not what you want...

Comment: If I'm not wrong with multicast you have a per-group (not per-client) encryption key.

Comment: How should a per-group key work? You can freely mix multicast packets with unicast packets. And that would also mean I should be able to sniff DHCP packets from other clients. Now I'm getting really curious ... you happen to know any docs?